# c6386 buffer overrun while writing - Pointers array

Tags: c, buffer-overrun

```
    Result putInDictionary(Dictionary* d, int key, int value)
{
    //If key is in dictionary, isKeyInDic holds the key's index, if not it holds -1
    int isKeyInDic = isKeyInDictionary(d, key);

    //If key is in dictionary, just repalce it's value and return Sucess
    if (isKeyInDic != -1)
    {
        setVal(d->pairsArray[isKeyInDic], value);
        return SUCEESS;
    }

    //Create a new pair
    Pair* pair = createPair(key, value);

    if (d->size == 0)
    {
        d->pairsArray = malloc(sizeof(Pair*));

        if (d->pairsArray == NULL)
        {
            printf("Malloc failed\n");
            return MEM_ERROR;
        }

        d->size++;
        d->pairsArray[0] = pair;
        return SUCEESS;
    }

    /*Case it's a new key and the dictionary isn't empty, expand the array with realloc
      Declare a backup pointer in case realloc failes
      Try to expand array's size by 1 (size of Element)
    */

    Pair** backup = d->pairsArray;

    d->pairsArray = realloc(d->pairsArray, sizeof(Pair*) * (d->size + 1));

    //Case realloc failed
    if (d->pairsArray == NULL)
    {
        printf("Malloc has failed\n");
        d->pairsArray = backup;
        return MEM_ERROR;
    }

    //Insertion sort - make sure all of the elements entered to the dictionary are sorted
    for (int i = 0; i < d->size; i++)
    {
        //Case an element with a bigger key than the new element's key is found
        if (getKey(d->pairsArray[i]) > key)
        {
            //Promote size with 1
            d->size++;

            //Move all of the elements from the element found 1 to the right
            for (int j = d->size - 1; j > i; j--)
            {
                d->pairsArray[j] = d->pairsArray[j - 1];
            }

            //Insert the new element in the place the bigger element's key is found
            d->pairsArray[i] = pair;

            return SUCEESS;
        }
    }

    /*Case the new element's key is bigger than any of the others
      Promote size with 1
      Insert the new element in the last spot of the array
    */
    d->size++;

    d->pairsArray[d->size - 1] = pair;

    return SUCEESS;
}
```

I have errors in 2 lines:

1. `getKey(d->pairsArray[i])`
2. `d->pairsArray[d->size - 1] = pair;`

I can't seem to understand why.
Those are the structs:

```
    struct Pair
{
    int key;
    int val;
};


    struct Dictionary
{
    Pair** pairsArray;
    int size;
};
```

It says that 8 bytes might be read but I can't understand how it's possible.
I know I can ignore it but I still want to have a if check that will prevent it anyways.

[Those are the error given to the lines I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Dxn.png)

Comment: "It says that 8 bytes might be read" What says that? Please edit your question to include the full and exact error messages.

Comment: Some of the referenced things are not defined in the shown code. Please make a [mre].

Comment: I've added a picute

Comment: Just fyi, your insertion logic is overt. You can allocate your new record, expand the pointer bed, put the new record on the end, then simply bubble it *down*, swapping with each predecessor pointer until the is-less-than comparison results to false and/or you've reached the beginning of the sequence, whichever comes first. No special case for whether the new item belongs at *either* "end" is required. Further, so long as your initial pointer bed is NULL when empty, you can also forego special-casing first-insertion, since NULL is acceptable for the first argument to `realloc`.

Comment: And regarding your "I know I can ignore it" - no, no you can't. Ok. I suppose you *could*, but it certainly wouldn't be wise. Coding without wisdom should be avoided; not accepted.